# Issues reading two text files and calculating values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two text files with numbers that I want to do some very easy calculations on (for now). I though I would go with Python. I have two file readers for the two text files:

```
with open('one.txt', 'r') as one:
    one_txt = one.readline()
print(one_txt)

with open('two.txt', 'r') as two:
    two_txt = two.readline()
print(two_txt)
```

Now to the fun (and for me hard) part. I would like to loop trough all the numbers in the second text file and then subtract it with the second number in the first text file.

I have done this (extended the coded above):

```
with open('two.txt') as two_txt:
   for line in two_txt:
       print line;
```

I don't know how to proceed now, because I think that the second text file would need to be converted to string in order do make some parsing so I get the numbers I want. The text file (two.txt) looks like this:

```
Start,End
2432009028,2432009184,
2432065385,2432066027,
2432115011,2432115211,
2432165329,2432165433,
2432216134,2432216289,
2432266528,2432266667,
```

I want to loop trough this, ignore the Start,End (first line) and then once it loops only pick the first values before each comma, the result would be:

```
2432009028
2432065385
2432115011
2432165329
2432216134
2432266528
```

Which I would then subtract with the second value in one.txt (contains numbers only and no Strings what so ever) and print the result.

There are many ways to do string operations and I feel lost, for instance I don't know if the methods to read everything to memory are good or not.

Any examples on how to solve this problem would be very appreciated (I am open to different solutions)!

**Edit: Forgot to point out, one.txt has values without any comma, like this:**

```
102582
205335
350365
133565
```

Comment: The first step would probably be to use `split` on the lines in `two.txt` to get a list. Replace `print line;` (the semi-colon is not needed, but that's beside the point) with `print line.split(',')`. You'll see you get a list, and you could take the 0th index to get the first of the two numbers: `print line.split(',')[0]`. The next part would be to look how to skip the first line. And so forth. Break the problem down into discrete steps or it's overwhelming.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Your question is tagged as python-3.x, but `print line;` is not valid Python 3.x.  It will work in Python 2.x though.

Comment: @huck_cussler 2.7 at the moment, thanks for pointing out! But if there is a deal breaker, something much nicer and easier in 3.x I will just upgrade :)

Comment: @usr2564301 no, one value per line, thanks for pointing out. Edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
with open('one.txt', 'r') as one, open('two.txt', 'r') as two:
    next(two) # skip first line in two.txt
    for line_one, line_two in zip(one, two):
        one_a = int(split(line_one, ",")[0])
        two_b = int(split(line_two, " ")[1])
        print(one_a - two_b)
```

Comment: Many thanks, will try is out soon. Could you please see my edit (sorry for the inconvenience) :)

Comment: Tested it, got: `File "test.py", line 3 with open('one.txt', 'r') as one, open('two.txt', 'r') as two:` SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Multiple bindings in `with` statements is Python3 syntax. For Python2, you could use nested with statements. Or switch over to Python3, because Python2 will be dead soon. ;-)

Comment: @Omni Roger that! Will switch. Many thanks that you could offer your time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onearray = []
file = open("one.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    onearray.append(int(line.replace("\n", "")))
file.close()

twoarray = []
file = open("two.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    if line != "Start,End\n":
        twoarray.append(int(line.split(",")[0]))
file.close()

for i in range(0, len(onearray)):
    print(twoarray[i] - onearray[i])
```

It should do the job!

Comment: Many thanks, will try it out soon. Could you please see my edit (sorry for the inconvenience) :)